# LINQ single record forms or defaults if no record

Tags: c#, linq

I am new to LINQ and am liking it so far, however I am trying to load in some forms by requesting a single record (student). If this doesn't exist I want't default values i.e. empty strings false bools...

so I used:

```
db = new DataClassesDataContext();        
student = db.ss_students.SingleOrDefault(p => p.student_id == studentID);
txtRegNumber.EditValue = student.car_reg_no;
```

This failed on the assignment of student.car_reg_no. I realised I seem to have mis-understood the SingleOrDefault method and it actually returns null for the student if it can't find a record. I for some reason was thinking it would return the default values for each of the fields such as student.car_reg_no. I think I am still thinkign in database mode.

This is not a problem I can do code like this:

```
db = new DataClassesDataContext();        
student = db.ss_students.SingleOrDefault(p => p.student_id == studentID);
if (student != null) 
{
        txtRegNumber.Text = student.car_reg_no;
        //assign more control values
}
```

And the defaults could either be assigned to the controls in an else or assigned direct on the form.

But is this the right way to do it or am I missing something?

**EDIT**
Thanks for the posts so far I have started the approach suggested by Marc Gravell. I have now got a bit further.

I am now trying to save the data back to the database how would I know if I am updating or inserting a record. Should I be adding bools to record this myself or is their a built in way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

SingleOrDefault returns the **default value for the returned type**. Which is

- null for classes/interfaces/delegates
- 0/false for value types

  - except for `Nullable<T>`, where it is null

For classes, you get null - this is mainly a way to check "did it exist?". Just create the actual default yourself... perhaps:

```
YourType x = query.SingleOrDefault() ?? new YourType();
```

This "null coalescing" approach only executes the right-hand-side (`new ...`) if the left-hand-side is null. Or more simply:

```
YourType x = query.SingleOrDefault();
if(x==null) { // use a default
    x = new YourType();
}
```

Comment: `FirstOrDefault` would be *slightly* cheaper if the ids can never be duplicates. `SingleOrDefault` will check that each time. (This isn't an issue with your answer, it's a comment in case the OP requested some unnecessary validation in the response.)

Comment: Thanks started doing it this way have just added an edit to keep it in the same post for others. What happens when I want to save the data do I not need to know if it is (in sql terms) an insert or an update command.

Comment: Since this is LINQ-to-SQL, worst case is that it has to read two rows from the database before throwing the exception...

Comment: @petebob796; interesting... you could use the `if` test and use `InsertOnSubmit` immediately, or you could check the primary key values later?

Comment: I think FirstOrDefault is a bit of a micro optimization for me. As I am learning I would prefer to get an error on more than one record in case I made a mistake on the lambada.

Comment: @Marc if I use the InsertOnSubmit straight away is it ok to set the student values after? so I would assign student.car_reg_no a value after the InsertOnSubmit line. I think it is as the student object wouldn't be used until the actual submit.

Comment: I believe so, yes. But it should be easy to find out (just check what values get saved...)